# Вывод изображений в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Создаю пост в блоге.
Часть кода из контроллера PostController

```html
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
    {
        
       $image = ($request->image->store('posts'));
      
        Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'image' => $request->image         
        ]);
       

        session()->flash('success','Пост успішно сворений');
        
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));

    }
```

Потом в файле index.blade.php беру и делаю вывод

```html
@foreach($posts as $post)
    
{{$post->image}}
            
@endforeach
```

Проблемма в том что изображение выводится вот так

```html
W:\userdata\temp\php6A4A.tmp
```

А мне нужен вид

```html
posts/gfdgfdgdgd.jpeg
```

кто знает как решить проблемму. 
Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Проблемма решилась когда я поправил две строки кода

```html
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
    {
        
       $image = $request->image->store('posts'); - тут убрал скобки
      
        Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'image' => $image    - тут картинка       
        ]);
       

        session()->flash('success','Пост успішно сворений');
        
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));

    }
```